# What is the reason of being my web api cancelled when I call through fetch api?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to access my asp.net core 6 Web API (.NET6) from client side fetch api in JavaScript/jQuery.

I have a service called payment api. When I send a call with required parameters and I hit the debugger then It shows me the flow line by line in the visual studio 2022.

There was nothing to stop the flow even a single statement nor even any error.

But when I am calling through fetch API then it is automatically send the cancelled response back .

This is the client side call.
see my components and error below

```
let resultPaymentPage = [];
     const settingsPaymentPage = {
         method: "POST",
         headers: {
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(requestPaymentObj)
     };
     try {
         debugger;
         const responsePaymentPage = await fetch(APP_SubmitPaymentForm, settingsPaymentPage);
         if (responsePaymentPage && !responsePaymentPage.ok) {
             resultDriverDetailPage = [];
         }
         else {           
             resultPaymentPage = await responsePaymentPage.json();
             debugger;     
             if (resultPaymentPage) {
                 loadThankYouPage(requestPaymentObj);
             }
    
         }
     } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
     }
```

The occurred the very first line . see below

```
 const responsePaymentPage = await fetch(APP_SubmitPaymentForm, settingsPaymentPage);
```

The server side api is a bit long logic and after persisting the data in the tables , there is an email which is being sent to the end user.

What can be the issue ? How can I trouble shoot it to see the depth detail of the error?

[image]

please guide

Comment: is this code being run in a form submit event handler that doesn't prevent the default action of a form submit?

Comment: Yes, You are right. Will it work ? e.preventDefault(); let me try it

Comment: Pls check your button is `type="button"`. Debug your frontend and backend code step by step to see if any problem.

Comment: double check APP_SubmitPaymentForm url ..is it correct?

Comment: Issue has been fixed. thank you all. the first click in my mind was missing the e.preventDefault(). this was the issue. Now it is working.